# Linux filtering a file by two columns and printing the output

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I have a table that has 9 columns as shown below.

[image]

How would I first sort by the strand column so only those with a "+" are selected, and then of those I select the ones that have 3 exons (In the exon count column).

I have been trying to use grep for this as I understand I can pick out a word from a column, but I only get the particular column or just the total number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance of how to ask a question so that you will get quality answers. Presumably this data is either in a SQL database, a CSV file or a spreadsheet. The solution will depend on how you have the data

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea how to check that - ask someone who has provided the data to you

Comment: @JamesSmith: is it a CSV file i.e separated by comma ?

Comment: I suggest sharing what you have so far. That makes it easier for people to comment/suggest/improve on where you are stuck.

Comment: I rolled your edit back to restore the question. Don't delete your question after it's been answered. Leave it here so others can benefit (that's the whole point of Stack Overflow). If you're happy with an answer below, click the check mark to mark it as correct and up-vote the answer so the answerer gets credited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using **awk**

```
awk -F "," ' $4=="+" && $9=="3" ' file.csv
```

If it's not CSV then remove `-F ","` from this command